# Click object by classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying `document.getElementsByClassName('classname').click();`, but it doesn't fire the click on the class. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because the `getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of DOM elements. And calling a click method on an array hardly makes sense. If you want to call this click method you could do that on some particular element of the array. For example if you wanted to call it on the first element (assuming the array is not empty of course):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();
```

But since you have tagged your question with jQuery you probably just wanted to write:

```
$('.classname').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that will return a set of elements, which is usually an `HTMLCollection`. You have to then iterate through it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Pure Javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('xxx');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(){window.alert('Class name is xxx');},false);
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.xxx').on('click',function(){window.alert('Class name is xxx');});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('classname')` returns an array of DOM nodes.

Try:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
     nodes[i].click();
}
```

Also remember that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by every browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.classname').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();
```

But, if you use jquery then

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
       $('.classname').on('click',function(event){});
    });
```

OR simply `$('.classname').click();`

Comment: `$('.classname').on('click',function(event){});` binds an event handler. It is not equivalent to `$('.classname').click();`.